# Hiding the full username in Ubuntu's Panel

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity, main-desktop-panel

Is there any way to hide the full user's name in Ubuntu's/Unity's Panel? i.e. the one that is displayed next to the small user icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name can be hidden by starting `dconf-editor` and disabling the option *show-real-name-on-panel* in the *apps/indicator-session* subtree.